# Django read files from directory and save their names in database

Tags: python, django

I am reading files from a directory and want to store the name of the files to the database table(postgresql). The problem is that the code first create an instance on the table on the first iteration and after that updates that record instead it should create the second instance until all file names are stored.

```
for image in glob.glob(path):
    if not os.path.isfile('thumbnails/' + os.path.basename(image)):
        print(image,"=====",number)
        im = Image.open(image)
        im.thumbnail((512, 512), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        im.save("thumbnails/" + os.path.basename(image), "JPEG")

        photo.name = os.path.basename(image)
        photo.size = os.path.getsize(image)
        photo.path = "thumbnails"
        photo.date = datetime.now()

        photo.save()
        number = number + 1
```

Comment: can you try this `photo.save(force_insert=True)`

Comment: Thanks dear this worked perfectly! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: anytime mate :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're reusing `photo` instance in the for loop. Try creating new instance of that model for every iteration instead.